# xskak wont parse 0-0

Tags: chess, xskak

Okay so I used to do a table for chess moves and import a picture from 
some online service to write chess stuff in LaTeX.
Now I found [`xskak`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xskak), and that is really a lot nicer and easier.
But I can't trick `xskak` into accepting 0-0 for a move, why is that?
It gives me a ZZ directly before the move in the output and my later diagram 
shows up without that move.
Is ther some other notation for castling?

Comment: As far as I can see, it's `O-O` (letter "O", not zero).

Comment: awesome, why I didn't figure that out myself I am not entirely sure. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castling), castling is denoted in [Portable Game Notation (PGN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation) by O-O and O-O-O rather than 0-0 and 0-0-0 (the former are letters "O", the latter digits "0").

Apparently `xskak` adheres to PGN.

So the answer is "use O-O and O-O-O".

Comment: Addition: Ulrike wrote in the `xskak`documentation: “The package `xskak` is an extension for the package `skak`. The package `skak` is a package from Torben Hoffmann which can parse and print chess games given in (a subset of) the PGN notation.”