# xskak wont correctly display castle \ParseCastling doesn't match its definition

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak, skak

Hello I am using xskak and I hit the issue which I have to solve: castling
I understand you have to use letter not digit as noted [here][1]
But my issue is when I use `O-O` I hit error in building PDF:
`! Use of \ParseCastling doesn't match its definition.<argument> ... \Castling {\True}\ParseCastling(ZO-OZ)`

My code is :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xskak}%skak version 1.5
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \newchessgame
    \mainline{1.Nf3 d5 2. c4 d4 3. g3 Nc6 4. Bg2 Nf6 5.  }
    \chessboard
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am pretty much without ideas here as it seems that for others this is working. Any idea please?

Thank you!
[1]: [xskak wont parse 0-0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78681/xskak-wont-parse-0-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slovak makes the hyphen active and this confuses the parsing. Deactivate the shorthand:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xskak}%skak version 1.5
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]%fragile so that \shorthandoff works
    \newchessgame
    \shorthandoff{-}
    \mainline{1.Nf3 d5 2. c4 d4 3. g3 Nc6 4. Bg2 Nf6 5. O-O  }
    \chessboard
\end{frame}

\end{document}

~~~~
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I spend lot of time on this issue and I should start without specific language. Issue is fixed and castling is working as well as notation.